# V-model inside v-for is filling all the inputs

Tags: vue.js, v-for, v-model

In few words I have multiple Todolists, once I try to post a new Todo inside the Todolist all the inputs of other Todolists gets fill in with the same words. How can I solve this?

Edit: I can post a new todo without problems and it will appear on the relative todolist (see addTodo method). The ONLY problem is that the v-model is for all the todolists on the field, not only for the one I'm writing in, so as soon as I start to write inside an input I got all the inputs filled.

```
      <div class="todolist" v-for="todolist in todolists" :key="todolist.id">

        <div class="td-title">
          <h5 class="text-center m-0 py-2 text-light">
            {{ todolist.title }}
          </h5>
        </div>

        <form
          @submit.prevent="addTodo(todolist.id)"
          class="td-inputs d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
        > 
          // this is the v-model
          <input v-model="todo.title" class="px-2" type="text" />
          <button type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
          </button>
        </form>

        <div>
          <div v-for="todo in todolist.todos" :key="todo.id" class="todo">
            {{ todo.title }}
          </div>

          <div>
            <i class="fas fa-times" @click="cancel(todolist.id)"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

data

```
data() {
    return {
      todolists: [],
      loading: true,
      todo: {
        title: "",
        todolist_id: "",
        user_id: ""
      },
    };
  },
```

Methods

```
getTodoLists() {
      axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todolists")
        .then((res) => {
          this.todolists = res.data;
          this.loading = false;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },

    cancel(id) {
      axios
        .delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todolists/${id}`)
        .then(() => {
          this.getTodoLists();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
    addTodo(todolist) {
      axios
        .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${todolist}/todos`, this.todo)
        .then(() => {
          this.todo = {}
          this.getTodoLists();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
```

Like down here: I'm writing on the left input and it shows even on the right input.

[image]

SOLVED:

With this computed property (with setter and getter) I solved my problem, now just the input in which I'm typing in is filled, and the todo can be post without a problem.

```
computed: {
    getTitle: {
      get: function () {
        return "";
      },

      set: function (value) {
        
        this.todo.title = value;
       
      },
    },
  },
```

And this is the v-model with the new computed property instead of todo.title

```
 <form
    @submit.prevent="addTodo(todolist.id)"
    class="td-inputs d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
 >
     <input v-model="getTitle" class="px-2" type="text" />
     <button type="submit">
        <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
     </button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible link  in jsfiddle or codepen ?

Comment: What does `addTodo` do? If it just puts the object into a list then they all point to the same object and therefore they all change.

Comment: addTodo put the todo in the relative list, that works good: if I submit the todo in the left todolist, the newtodo will be added in the left todolist. Same for the right one, the only problem is that both inputs visually returns the v-model

Comment: you need to always make sure you have at least one empty item in todolists (for new item), then use the index to find it for save etc, or split the new item out from the for loop, then you can use `v-model="todo.title"` otherwise it needs to be v-model="todolist.title"

Comment: What do you mean for "empty item in todolists"? Then I can't do a v-model on "todolist.title", it wouldn't work.

Comment: add your solution to an answer

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable in data called "todo" and then you are reusing that variable name inside your inner v-for:

```
<div v-for="todo in todolist.todos" :key="todo.id" class="todo">
    {{ todo.title }}
</div>
```

I think todo is referring to the todo from your data, not from the v-for. Thus, all todo items refer to the same variable. Try to rename one of them and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: As soon as I'll get home I will try, it can be, I didn't even notice that

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your input to your `todo` declared data object.
Instead, you should bind your input to your `todolist` object in this way:

```
<div class="todolist" v-for="todolist in todolists" :key="todolist.id">
    ....
    <input v-model="todolist.title" class="px-2" type="text" />
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: In that way I don't solve the problem, cause todolist.title is the title of the todolist, maybe a watcher or computed setters and getters could help?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

With this computed property (with setter and getter) I solved my problem, now just the input in which I'm typing in is filled, and the todo can be post without a problem.

```
computed: {
    getTitle: {
      get: function () {
        return "";
      },

      set: function (value) {
        
        this.todo.title = value;
       
      },
    },
  },
```

And this is the v-model with the new computed property instead of todo.title

```
 <form
    @submit.prevent="addTodo(todolist.id)"
    class="td-inputs d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
 >
     <input v-model="getTitle" class="px-2" type="text" />
     <button type="submit">
        <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
     </button>
 </form>
```